# Schedule a job with Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have the following requirement.

1. A product has n user
2. Every user has the option to set one day+time per weak for a notification
3. Timezone must be considered as well

The complete info is stored inside a mongo db. But now I ask myself should I create cron jobs for every user and notification or setup a task?

Comment: One solution is the other way around: have a job that runs every minute, that checks which notifications are to send in that minute.

Comment: I thought about the same. Using either Quartz or the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. But I have some concerns regarding system load.

Comment: You have to handle the notifications anyway. So maybe you need two jobs, the first one (very fast, able to handle high peeks) detect the notifications that needs to be send, and put into some queue (in a database table, or just a java Queue. The second job (slower, but now it is buffered) send the notfications from the queue. If the queue is done by a database table, then you likely need a second scheduled job, if it is done by a  java Queue, then you could use for example a java TransferQueue with a high capacity.